# SimpleDateFormat parsing »today« and »yesterday«

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am parsing time and date which the date can show as the following

"today, 7:43 am"
"yesterday, 7:33 am"
"august 21, 6:48 am"

I know how to parse for "august 21, 6:48 am" but is there anything build in to handle "today" and "yesterday"?

Comment: Unless you sit down and write a parser yourself, to the best of my knowledge, the JDK doesn't have a facility to do this. You may want to take a look at [natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/). I haven't tried it extensively, but it seems to work with all the examples you've given in the question.

Comment: No, there's nothin built-in. If there was, the documentation would talk about it.

Comment: @Mureinik Thanks for recommending Natty. It works perfectly. But it keeps printing log messages like "303113 [Thread1] INFO com.joestelmach.natty.Parser - STREAM: AUGUST WHITE_SPACE INT_22 COMMA WHITE_SPACE INT_7 COLON INT_31 WHITE_SPACE AM"  Is there anyway to turn these log messages off?

Comment: @Mureinik Also you can write your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

If you look at actual [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API reference, you will see, that there are no such patterns (for `yesterday`, `today`) defined.

For this particular task you need to implement your own parser.